# How to use signals to make changes to other models

Tags: django, django-models, signals

I have two models in my project, The LoanApplication and OnlineLoanPayment model. I would like to implement a feature where whenever someone makes a payment in OnlineLoanPayment model ,I want a the loanarrears field to be decremented by the amount paid using djnago signals.

Below are my models and signals file.

```html
class OnlineLoanPayment (models.Model):
    Amount = models.FloatField(default=0,null=True,blank=True)
    ReceiptNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    PhoneNumber = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    TransactionDate = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
```

Here is the LoanApplication  model

```html
class LoanApplication(models.Model):
  load_id = models.CharField(max_length=25,blank=True,null=True)
  amountApplied = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
  models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True,auto_now_add=True)
  interest = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
  repayamentDuedate = models.DateTimeField(null=True,blank=True)
  loanArears = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
  totalRepaymentAmount = models.FloatField(null=True,blank=True)
  is_cleared = models.BooleanField(default=False)
  
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    loanApprovalDate = date.today()
    
    if not self.load_id:
      self.load_id = str(uuid.uuid4()).replace("-","").upper()[:5]
    

    if self.repayamentDuedate is None:
      self.repayamentDuedate = loanApprovalDate + datetime.timedelta(self.repayment_duration)

    if self.interest is None:
      self.interest = self.amountApplied /  100 * self.interestRate

    if not self.totalRepaymentAmount:
      self.totalRepaymentAmount = self.amountApplied + self.interest
      
    if  self.loanArears is None:
      self.loanArears = self.totalRepaymentAmount
    
    if self.loanArears == 0:
      self.is_cleared = True
    return super(LoanApplication,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
  
  class Meta:
    verbose_name = ("Loan Application")
    verbose_name_plural = ("Loan Applications")
```

```html
from .models import *
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from mpesa.models import OlineLoanRepayment

@receiver(post_save,sender=OlineLoanRepayment)
def post_save_update_arears(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
  if created:
    amount = OlineLoanRepayment.objects.all()
    for item in amount:
      print(item.Amount)
      # decrement the loanares field in the LoanApplication field by the amount value
```

Comment: what is `OlineLoanRepayment`?

Comment: OlineLoanRepayment is model

Comment: A different model from `OnlineLoanPayment`?

Comment: Nop,its the exact same model

Comment: I have the OnlineLoanPayment and LoanApplication model,so I want to decrement the loan arrears value in the LoanApplication model whenever a payment is made  in the OnlineLoanPayment  model using django signals post_save